# Ubuntu Auto Suspend Problem

Tags: 20.04, suspend, lts

I have installed Ubuntu version 20.04.3 LTS. When the charging is disconnected, it automatically goes into sleep mode. It works fine when charging on.

Comment: Replace your laptop battery. It's clearly not holding a charge

Comment: @waltinator He doesn't say that the battery discharges, he says that his computer suspends when he disconnects the charger, which is a simple fix... Hopefully

Answer (score 0):

In the GNOME settings menu, select the `power` tab. You should see a `suspend` option.

If there is no `suspend` option, then I recommend trying to use a program called `gnome-tweaks`. Install this by running `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks` and go to the power menu.

I hope this helps.